# Powershell script to get all Sharepoint user id and user login

Tags: user-profile, forms-authentication, export, login

I am importing data into a SharePoint list. One of the columns is the user's login/name which links to their profile via their SharePoint user id.

> FARMURL/userdisp.aspx?ID=56

In order to import correctly, I first need to pull out the id and login, so that I can match them to their appropriate rows, then import the data accordingly.

How can I get the logins and ids?

Answer (score 3):

This could work, but only for a given **SPWeb**:

```
Get-SPUser -Web http://localhost | ForEach-Object { $_.Id }
```

Comment: To get the name you can try $_.Name, like this: `ForEach-Object{ "" + $_.Id + " " + $_.Name }`